# R Markdown Dataframe with Kable

Tags: r, r-markdown, pipeline, kable

I'm creating an R Markdown file, and I'm adding data frames to the report.

Dataframes are working fine, but I want to convert them into a table. I read a solution that we can do by extracting the data into a variable and then putting the variable in the kable function, but I want to do it all in one code chunk using pipelines.

This is the code:

```
sales %>% group_by(Town = 'Avon', Year) %>%
  summarise(sale_price = sum(Sale.Amount)) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  kable(head(5)) #without kable function, works perfectly fine.
```

It says kable function was unable to be found.

Any ideas to improve the data frames' appearance in R Markdown?

This is the data frame in R Markdown

[image]

Comment: Have you loaded the packages like: ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)```

Comment: Yes, it still says 

'Error in Kable_("Greenwich", "Darien"... Not able to find function "kable_". Calls: <Anonymus> ... eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval -> eval %>% able -> do.call.

Comment: Could you please share your complete code including the packages you load?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `head` function outside of the `kable` function, e.g.

```
sales %>% 
  group_by(Town = 'Avon', Year) %>%
  summarise(sale_price = sum(Sale.Amount)) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  head(5) %>%
  kable()
```